# Validate date in a CL program (AS400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Hi can someone tell me how to validate date in a CL program. If a DATE is provided as an input to the CL program , the CL program should validate the provided DATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a CL command named `CVTDAT`. Use it to convert a date from one format to another. To validate the date, use the `MONMSG` command to monitor for any conversion error.

```
            PGM        PARM(&CHDATE)                                  
                                                                      
            dcl        &chdate *char 10                               
            dcl        &todate *char 10                               
            dcl        &errmsg *char 256                              
                                                                      
            CVTDAT     DATE(&CHDATE) TOVAR(&TODATE) FROMFMT(*YYMD) +  
                         TOFMT(*ISO) TOSEP(*NONE)                     
            monmsg     cpf0000 exec(do)                               
            RCVMSG     MSGTYPE(*EXCP) MSG(&errMSG)                    
            enddo                                                     
                                                                      
            IF         COND(&ERRMSG *NE ' ') THEN(SNDPGMMSG +         
                         MSG('date convert error.' *BCAT &ERRMSG))    
            else       do                                             
            SNDPGMMSG  MSG('resulting date:' *BCAT &TODATE)           
            enddo                                                     
                                                                      
            endpgm
```